# Merge multiple sprite nodes?

Tags: image, textures, godot, gdscript

For example, let's say I have 2 sprite nodes (but could also be more than 2) like this:

[image]

with each having their own separate images
What I want is to combine them and create a new sprite node with a single image (in tool mode)

like this:
[image]

Perhaps it's possible by using [`Image`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_image.html)? (involving calculations no doubt)
or maybe something using [`VisualServer`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.4/classes/class_visualserver.html#class-visualserver-signal-frame-post-draw)?

Comment: That should be possible. In particular if you only want the sprites without any additional effects or shaders. However, in general, I would consider rendering them to another `Viewport`, and then taking the texture from there.

Comment: @Theraot I was hoping there was some inbuilt method where you can simply pass the nodes you want drawn to the VisualServer and it spits out an image but oh well :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution,

```
tool
extends Sprite

export (Vector2) var img_size setget set_img_size
export (String) var img_path = "res://MergeImg.png"
export (bool) var generate_img = false setget set_generate_img

var ep_filesystem=EditorPlugin.new().get_editor_interface().get_resource_filesystem()

func set_img_size(new_val):
    img_size=new_val
    update()

func _draw():
    draw_rect(Rect2(0,0,img_size.x,img_size.y), Color(0,200,0), false, 1.0)

func set_generate_img(new_val):
    if(not new_val):
        return
    
    var screenshot_viewport=Viewport.new()
    screenshot_viewport.size=img_size
    screenshot_viewport.hdr=false
    screenshot_viewport.transparent_bg=true
    screenshot_viewport.render_target_v_flip=true
    
    for child in get_children():
        remove_child(child)
        screenshot_viewport.add_child(child)
    
    add_child(screenshot_viewport)
    
    screenshot_viewport.set_update_mode(Viewport.UPDATE_ONCE)
    yield(VisualServer,"frame_post_draw")
    
    var mergeImg=screenshot_viewport.get_texture().get_data()
    mergeImg.save_png(img_path)
    
    for child in screenshot_viewport.get_children():
        screenshot_viewport.remove_child(child)
        add_child(child)
        child.set_owner(get_tree().get_edited_scene_root())
    screenshot_viewport.queue_free()
    
    ep_filesystem.scan()
    yield(ep_filesystem,"filesystem_changed")
    
    texture=load(img_path)
    centered=false
    region_enabled=true
    region_rect=Rect2(0,0,img_size.x,img_size.y)
    
    print("Merged Images!")

func _init():
    self_modulate=Color("#74646464")
```

once you press `generate_img` it creates an image like this:
[image]

The reason I added `self_modulate=Color("#74646464")` is so that there is no confusion between the merged image and the child sprites (like a ghost image)

[image]

Though I still feel like there might be a better solution, if so please post one

**Edit:**

For Centered offset

```
func _draw():
    var origin_x=0
    var origin_y=0
    if(centered):
        origin_x=-img_size.x/2
        origin_y=-img_size.y/2
    print("Redrawing")
    draw_rect(Rect2(origin_x,origin_y,img_size.x,img_size.y), Color(0,200,0), false, 1.0)

func set_generate_img(new_val=true):
    if(not new_val):
        return
    
    var screenshot_viewport=Viewport.new()
    screenshot_viewport.size=img_size
    screenshot_viewport.hdr=false
    screenshot_viewport.transparent_bg=true
    screenshot_viewport.render_target_v_flip=true
    if(centered):
        screenshot_viewport.global_canvas_transform.origin=Vector2(img_size.x/2,img_size.y/2)
    
    for child in get_children():
        remove_child(child)
        screenshot_viewport.add_child(child)
    
    add_child(screenshot_viewport)
    
    screenshot_viewport.set_update_mode(Viewport.UPDATE_ONCE)
    yield(VisualServer,"frame_post_draw")
    
    var mergeImg=screenshot_viewport.get_texture().get_data()
    mergeImg.save_png(img_path)
    
    for child in screenshot_viewport.get_children():
        screenshot_viewport.remove_child(child)
        add_child(child)
        child.set_owner(get_tree().get_edited_scene_root())
    screenshot_viewport.queue_free()
    
    ep_filesystem.scan()
    yield(ep_filesystem,"filesystem_changed")
    
    texture=load(img_path)
    region_enabled=true
    region_rect=Rect2(0,0,img_size.x,img_size.y)
```

**Edit 2:**

Fix for darker transparent images, thanks a million to [Theraot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74499502/15182215) (upvote it!)

```
tool
extends Sprite

export (Vector2) var img_size setget set_img_size
export (String) var img_path = "res://MergeImg.png"
export (bool) var generate_img = false setget set_generate_img

var ep_filesystem=EditorPlugin.new().get_editor_interface().get_resource_filesystem()

func set_img_size(new_val):
    img_size=new_val
    update()

func _draw():
    var origin_x=0
    var origin_y=0
    if(centered):
        origin_x=-img_size.x/2
        origin_y=-img_size.y/2
    print("Redrawing")
    draw_rect(Rect2(origin_x,origin_y,img_size.x,img_size.y), Color(0,200,0), false, 1.0)

func set_generate_img(new_val=true):
    if(not new_val):
        return
    
    var screenshot_viewport=Viewport.new()
    screenshot_viewport.size=img_size
    screenshot_viewport.hdr=false
    screenshot_viewport.transparent_bg=true
    screenshot_viewport.render_target_v_flip=true
    if(centered):
        screenshot_viewport.global_canvas_transform.origin=Vector2(img_size.x/2,img_size.y/2)
    
    for child in get_children():
        remove_child(child)
        screenshot_viewport.add_child(child)
    
    add_child(screenshot_viewport)
    
    screenshot_viewport.set_update_mode(Viewport.UPDATE_ONCE)
    yield(VisualServer,"frame_post_draw")
    
    var mergeImg=screenshot_viewport.get_texture().get_data()
    ### unmultiplication ###
    mergeImg.lock()
    for y in mergeImg.get_size().y:
        for x in mergeImg.get_size().x:
            var color:Color = mergeImg.get_pixel(x, y)
            if color.a != 0:
                mergeImg.set_pixel(x, y, Color(color.r / color.a, color.g / color.a, color.b / color.a, color.a))
    mergeImg.unlock()
    ###
    mergeImg.save_png(img_path)
    
    for child in screenshot_viewport.get_children():
        screenshot_viewport.remove_child(child)
        add_child(child)
        child.set_owner(get_tree().get_edited_scene_root())
    screenshot_viewport.queue_free()
    
    ep_filesystem.scan()
    yield(ep_filesystem,"filesystem_changed")
    
    texture=load(img_path)

func _init():
    self_modulate=Color("#74646464")
```