# Scaling inside viewport

Tags: godot, gdscript

I Have a viewport and a scaled image inside like this:

[image]

both the images are scaled to 0.1 but the one inside the viewport is of less resolution
Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The `Viewport` has a `size`, that `size` sets the resolution at which the contents of the `Viewport` will be rendered. And it does not have to match the size at which it is displayed (it could be stretched/scaled).

With the `ViewportContainer` you can decide if it will automatically set the `size` of the `Viewport` or if it will `stretch` it (scaling the `ViewportContainer` will also result in stretchering). If you prefer to not use the `ViewportContainer`※, set the `size` of the `Viewport` in the Inspector or form code.

※: For example, you can display a `ViewportTexture` with a `TextureRect`, which will give you more control on how it is displayed. But it is less convinnient to setup.

Comment: so you're saying I'll have to resize each image to (1,1) and then scale the `ViewportContainer` using Rect? That would be really inconvenient as I'm trying to find a solution with respect to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74177491/18005234) in context